# Lebesgue integral is 0

Tags: real-analysis

$\int_a^b|f(x)|dx=0$ if and only if $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in [a,b]$ except of a set of measure 0.

One way is easy, but another is much harder. Any ideas?

I think both of the following two answer are correct.

Comment: It's not clear which way is the "easy" way.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you're saying it's easy to show the integral is $0$ if function is $0$ a.e.

for the other direction you assume the contrary. then the set where $|f| > 0$ is a union of sets on which $|f| > \frac{1}{n}$. one of those has to have strictly positive measure. can you conclude?

Edit:
I didn't really understand the last sentence in your comment, but the point is that 
$$\{ x : |f(x)| > 0\} \subset \bigcup_n \{x : |f(x)| > \frac{1}{n}\}$$
 hence $$\mu(\{ x : |f(x)| > 0\} ) \leq \mu( \bigcup_n \{x : |f(x)| > \frac{1}{n}\}) \leq \sum_n \mu( \{x : |f(x)| > \frac{1}{n}\})  $$
because $\mu$ is a measure (Lebesgue measure in our case). in fact since our family of sets is increasing you could take a limit of measures instead of a sum, but that doesn't matter. if all of the $1/n$ sets had measure $0$ then so would $\{x : |f(x)| > 0\}$

Comment: It looks fine to me. But when I try to write down. there arise a problem. How to make sure one of the set is strictly positive measure? Is it possible that union of part of the set with another is positive measure?

Comment: see my edit, although I'm not sure what was your doubt

Comment: got it! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let $X=\{x| \epsilon \leq |f(x)|\}$,  $X$ is measurable  and 
$$\epsilon \chi_X \leq |f|$$ so 
$$\int \epsilon \chi_X \leq \int |f|=0$$ and we see that $X$ has measure zero.
Now let $\epsilon =\frac{1}{n}$ and take the union of all the sets $X$.